# Pass an object directly to a value converter instead of manually copying it to a new object

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, aurelia, valueconverter

We are passing an object parameter to the following [value converter](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/binding-with-value-converters-in-aurelia/).

```
export class SortValueConverter {
  toView(array, config) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

We pass the object to the value converter by manually copying it to a new object.

```
<select value.bind="config">
    <option repeat.for="s of sortOptions"
            model.bind="s.config">${s.friendlyName}
    </option>
</select>

<div repeat.for="u of users | sort:{ prop: config.prop, dir: config.dir}">
```

We would like instead to pass the object directly.

```
<div repeat.for="u of users | sort:config">
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it exactly the way you would like. Check this example: https://gist.run/?id=49d1b3acf5fe7d168909a4f49dca152e

**MyItem.html**

```
<select value.bind="config">
    <option repeat.for="s of sortOptions"
            model.bind="s.config">${s.friendlyName}
    </option>
</select>
<div repeat.for="u of users | sort:config">
```

**MyItem.js** Make sure that you set a default value for your config!

```
export class MyItem {
  users = [];
  config;
  sortOptions = [
    { config: { propertyName: 'aaa', direction: 'ascending' }, friendlyName: 'aaa' },
    { config: { propertyName: 'bbb', direction: 'descending' }, friendlyName: 'bbb' },
    { config: { propertyName: 'ccc', direction: 'descending' }, friendlyName: 'ccc' }
  ];

  constructor(userRepo: UserRepository) {
    this.config = this.sortOptions[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you by chance have a really old version of the Aurelia libs that has a bug in it or something? We hit RC last week.

Comment: I am defining the sort configuration in the view whereas the gist that you created is defining it in the viewModel.

Comment: If you can distill it down to a gist.run, I'll do my best to help you figure out the issue.

Comment: It's figured out. I needed to set a default value for the config property. If that isn't done, then it's undefined when we first render the page.